# What are some special cases that statements should not be closed?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I've been told to almost always(!) close statements and connections after work is done.

However, I always get the urge to reuse frequently used statements.

What are some cases that I can reuse statements?

Comment: The whole point of prepared statements is that they be reused. Reusing a prepared statement avoids the server having to parse the statement and create an execution plan every time. You should only close statements when you are really finished with them.

Comment: @MikeW For a web server, when should I close statements?

Comment: @MikeW I doubt that's the main reason why prepared statements are used. I am quite sure it's because of parameterized queries to prevent SQL Injection.

Comment: Every piece of code is different. The only answer I can give is 'when you have finished using them'.

Comment: @FabianBarney One would get that impression from reading [so]. Protection against SQL injection is a useful side effect. Unfortunately, the woeful lack of understanding that accompanies so many questions (and many answers) leads to some seriously bad implementations that, while safe from SQL Injection, can be damagingly inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should close a statement (and connection) after completing a unit of work (or earlier if you no longer need it). An example where you can re-use a statement, is in a tight loop where you need to perform the same query with different input values (for example a bulk insert). In that case you prepare the statement outside the loop, and close it after the loop is done.

You shouldn't try to hold on to statements (or connections) for longer than a unit of work; trying to re-use inside code will probably lead to opaque and hard to understand code, lots of boiler plate and hard to track resource leaks or other bugs.

The only exception is when you use a connection pool implementation (which sometimes also provide statement pooling). There you don't have to think about it yourself (apart from the correct configuration of the pool), because you will close a statement and a connection on their natural boundaries. Instead of being really closed they are returned to the connection (or statement) pool.